# Laravel 5.4 - Associate two array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I would like to "associate" two array, i need to combine the date but to add the second line of data to the other array.

An exemple will be more understable :

Array 1 :

```
  array:2 [▼
  "July 2017" => 2
  "May 2017" => 1
]
```

Array 2 :

```
array:5 [▼
  "April 2017" => 1
  "July 2017" => 1
  "June 2017" => 1
  "March 2016" => 1
  "September 2016" => 1
]
```

The result :

```
array [
      ['April 2017', 1, 0],
      ['July 2017', 1, 2],
      ['June 2017', 1, 0],
      ['March 2016', 1, 0],
      ['September 2016', 1, 0],
      ['May 2017', 0, 1]
    ]
```

All month with same name (and year) are combine. Data from array 1 are add after the array 2. So it turn into an array of array.

But i can't find any function which do this job.

Thanks you for your help !

Comment: What have you tried until now? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I found things like `array_merge` but it's an addition and I need a little more than a simple addition

Comment: i think something is wrong in your result set please checked !!

Comment: i don't even understand your example ... example: in your result:  "June 2017" => 1, 2" but what does that 2 means?

Comment: hes trying to array_merge 2 arrays and than sum June (1+1) (all months with same name - I guess), but I do not know from where comes that 1 (from first or second array), cos he have in May 2017, 0 ?!

Comment: My bad i didn't realize that will be array of array, i fixed that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite easy to achieve.

```
<?php

$array1 = array(
    "July 2017" => 2,
    "May 2017" => 1
);

$array2 = array(
  "April 2017" => 1,
  "July 2017" => 1,
  "June 2017" => 1,
  "March 2016" => 1,
  "September 2016" => 1
);

$array3 = $array2 + $array1;
$out = array();

foreach( $array3 as $k=>$v )
{
    $out[] = array($k, (isset($array2[$k]) ? $array2[$k]:0), (isset($array1[$k]) ? $array1[$k]:0));
}

print_r( $out );
```

Result will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => April 2017
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => July 2017
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => June 2017
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => March 2016
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => September 2016
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => May 2017
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: Easy for you ;) Anyway it's working thanks !  If you have time to explain what happen in the foreach that would interest me

Comment: Well, $array3 is quite unrequired in current task, but all it used for is to get total array keys of $array1 and $array2, nothing more (I know, I know, it was dirty solution).
And then, foreach code just builds required array based on $array1 values and $array2 values.